# CMake - Unable to copy directory recursively

Tags: cmake

Here is my CMake Command:

```
add_custom_command(
        TARGET ${LibName} POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Resources
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Resources)
```

This copies only the main folder with no child folders or files contained in them. AKA it does no recursive copy.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Note: You should read the guidance on using tags in titles. See [ask] and [/help/tagging](/help/tagging) and ["What should I keep out of my posts and titles?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What CMake version do you have installed, and what version is specified in your project's `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION)` call?